# JQuery find element position base on other element

Tags: jquery

I have 2 div, small div(draggable) inside of big div

I need to find small div position count from big div top left corner, not from page.

big div position can be any where.(because page layout)

```
<div id='big'>
<div id='small'></div>
</div>
```

so if user didn't drag the small div, position will return 0, 0

```
var top=$('#small').position().top; 
alert(top);
```

what i have now is return the position from page, not from big div

http://jsfiddle.net/B72mQ/1/

Comment: give me a sec, i make it now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B72mQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/B72mQ/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#small').draggable({
        containment: "parent"
    });
    $('#click').click(function () {
        var rel_top = $("#small").css('top');
        var rel_left = $("#small").css('left');
        alert(rel_top + ', ' + rel_left);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#small').offset().top
```

Did you try using offset ?

Comment: The answer above by @Vanga should fix it all!

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery to get an element's position, we have two options

**offset()**

This is always relative to the document.

**Position()**

This is always relative to the element's offset parent.

*Offset Parent* : is the parent of current element which doesn't have a position value - static. It can have any other position value.

In your case, Add `position:relative` to big div.

**CSS Code**

```
#big { position : relative; }
```

Then the `position()` will give the position of small div relative to the big div.

Comment: when i user jquery draggable, it return 0 even i drag it, jsfiddle.net/B72mQ/1